# Extract File Name, File Row count and File size for each file

Tags: linux

Wondering any best way to capture the information of a group of files recursively in a folder and logging it as a separate pipe delimited file as shown below

Example of a output file .

```
FOLDER_NM|FILE_NM|FILE_CNT|FILE_SIZE|DATE . 

SOME_FLD|xyz|35|350 MB| 10-05-2018  
SOME_FLD|abc|10|440 MB| 10-05-2018
SOME_FLD|pqr|85|800 MB| 10-05-2018 
SOME_FLD|lmn|40|200 MB| 10-05-2018
```

Comment: is `DATE` today's date or the last modification time of the file? I'd suggest using `2018-10-05` which is more useful for sorting and also less ambiguous (to [most people outside the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country), 10-05-2018 is the 10th of May).

Answer (score 0):

Your `linux` tag suggests that `stat` and GNU `sed` are available on your system; thus try

```
stat -c"%n|%s|%y" SOME_FLD/* | sed -r 'h; s/\|.*$//; s/^/wc -l </e; G; s/\n/|/; s/^([^|]*\|)([^|]*\|)/\2\1/; s/( [^ ]*){2}$//; s#/#|#' 
SOME_FLD|abc|235|2808|2018-10-05
SOME_FLD|lnm|235|2808|2018-10-05
SOME_FLD|pqr|235|2808|2018-10-05
SOME_FLD|xyz|235|2808|2018-10-05
```

`stat` lists the necessary data fields; `sed`, after saving the line to the hold buffer, runs the `wc -l` command on the file name (GNU extension), then shuffles the relevant fields to the requested order, then does some cosmetics (removes time fields from the date, substitutes the `/` to `|` for the liles' paths).

Answer (score 0):

With recent versions of `perl`:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -exec perl -MPOSIX -MNumber::Bytes::Human=format_bytes -e '
  while (<<>>) { if (eof) {
    my ($d, $f) = $ARGV =~ m{.*/(.*)/(.*)}s;
    my @s = stat ARGV;
    print join("|", $d, $f, $., format_bytes(tell ARGV),
               strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime $s[9])) . "\n";
    close ARGV;
  }}' {} +
```

(note that it skips empty files, and (contrary to `wc -l`) does count characters after the last newline as a line).

Or with `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat
human() {
  local suffix
  REPLY=$1
  for suffix ('' K M G T P E) {
    ((REPLY<1024)) && break
    ((REPLY /= 1024.))
  }
  printf -v REPLY '%.1f%s' $REPLY $suffix
}
for file ($PWD/**/*(D-.)) {
  zstat -F %F -H info -- $file &&
    lines=$(($(wc -l < $file))) &&
    printf '%s\n' "$file:h:t|$file:t|$lines|$info[size]|$info[mtime]"
}
```

But that means running one `wc -l` per file which is going to be quite ineficient.

Comment: sorry if my question is confusing.... here is the simplified version...input folder has 5 files.. xyz.dat, pqr.dat, lmn.dat and abc.dat and i want to get the details of the files in iteration... wc -l of the file , name of the file and size of the file in a separate file name output.dat pipe delimited...